# componentsSeparatedByString backslash escape

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am having an issue with the NSString componentsSeparatedByString method.

Here it follows an example:

```
(lldb) p [[@"TEST\\¦TEST\\WORKS" componentsSeparatedByString:@"¦"] objectAtIndex: 0]
(NSTaggedPointerString *) $13 = 0xa00005c545345545 @"TEST\"
(lldb) p [[@"TEST\\¦TEST\\WORKS" componentsSeparatedByString:@"¦"] objectAtIndex: 1]
(__NSCFString *) $14 = 0x000000017023f440 @"TEST\\WORKS"
```

It seems to me that substrings with an escaped backslash at the end lose the correct escaping of the backslash `\\`.

In the example above I am expecting in the first case an NSString (`@"TEST\\"`) instead I get an NSTaggedPointerString (`@"TEST\"`) that has the last character not correctly escaped.

Am I doing something wrong or assuming the method should work differently?

I am asking this question since I have to use the substring inside an NSPredicate and I get the following exception:

```
NSArray *explodePair = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"¦"];
NSString *colorCode = [explodePair count] > 0 ? [explodePair firstObject] : nil;
[self.colors filteredOrderedSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code LIKE %@", colorCode]]
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The backslash is a wildcard
>   char, and cannot appear unescaped at the end of a string.'

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Add information about what you expect and what it gives you.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I updated the question

Comment: `@"TEST\\¦TEST\\WORKS"` creates string 'TEST\¦TEST\WORKS'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `NSTaggedPointerString` and `__NSCFString` are, confusingly, showing a single backslash in different ways in the LLDB output.

You can use `po` instead of `p` to see them the same way.

You can also use the `length` method on NSString to check that what `NSTaggedPointerString` shows as `\` but `__NSCFString` shows as `\\` is actually just a single character.